# Civi 4.4.6 forms not working with WordPress 4.3.1

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

After upgrading WordPress from 4.2.5 to 4.3.1, Civi Contribution forms return a blank page after submitting (clicking Confirm Contribution).

I would rather not downgrade WP but will if I have to. I don't have the resources to upgrade Civi at this time.

I've seen some similar issues reported here but don't have a solid lead yet. I will keep looking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it was the Jetpack plugin causing the problem and not the WP upgrade. I had installed Jetpack just after upgrading in an attempt to solve a different problem (unrelated to Civi). I should have tried disabling plugins before doing the downgrade, but previously no plugins were causing problems and I'd forgotten about the addition of Jetpack.